# Python 3/Doctest: Exception is not evaluated as expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

I have a python module containing (amongst other functions) this piece of code:

```
def check_color_range(*argv):
"""
Abbreviated documentation and other tests.

>>> check_color_range(23, -1, 99, 10000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!    
"""
for c in argv:
    if c < 0 or c > 255:
        raise TypeError('Falscher Farbwert ' + str(c) + '!')
```

When I run this using doctest like so: `python -m doctest -v demo.py`, I get the following output:

```
Trying:
    check_color_range(23, -1, 99, 10000)
Expecting:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!
**********************************************************************
File "C:\az\code_camp_python\src\EigeneProgramme\Tag3\arcade_base\demo.py", line 5, in demo.check_color_range
Failed example:
    check_color_range(23, -1, 99, 10000)
Expected:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!
Got:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\az\miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest demo.check_color_range[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        check_color_range(23, -1, 99, 10000)
      File "C:\az\code_camp_python\src\EigeneProgramme\Tag3\arcade_base\demo.py", line 12, in check_color_range
        raise TypeError('Falscher Farbwert ' + str(c) + '!')
    TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!
1 items had no tests:
    demo
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in demo.check_color_range
1 tests in 2 items.
0 passed and 1 failed.
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

For me the expected and the actual Errors look the same, but I may be missing something. I already compared whitespace etc., which seems to be the same.

I then tried to paste the complete Traceback from the "Got:" section into the testcase - and I'm still get the failed test, so I guess I must be doing something wrong.

I'd be very happy, if you could give me a heads-up.

Comment: From what I see, you are running `check_color_range(23, -1, 99, 10000)`. So of course, you will receive the message `TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!`, because your second argument is `-1`.

Comment: Yes and the testcase should accept this as an expected exception. You can see that doctest expects a Traceback, but states that the actual Traceback is different - and I cannot see where it differs.

Comment: In this case, maybe you should share the code that calls the `check_color_range` method, because it sound like there's the problem.

Comment: Well, I did that. You have the complete module code (first section) and the call (inlined code in the "When I run this..." sentence.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8 you have: `TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!____` (4 blank spaces at the end)

You should replace it with: `TypeError: Falscher Farbwert -1!`